# Unable to use custom directive when ng-model is used

Tags: angularjs

While trying to use custom directive with an output linked to text field im getting below issue

> [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'myDir' must have exactly one
>   root element.
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$compile/tplrt?p0=myDir&p1= can some
>   one show some light here

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp1">

<head>
    <title> ANGULAR</title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('myapp1', []).directive('myDir', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                replace: true,
                template: '<input type="text" ng-model="title"> {{title}}'
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <my-dir>sadas</my-dir>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message is clear I guess your template should look like this:

```
<div><input type="text" ng-model="title"> {{title}}</div>
```

instead of just:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="title"> {{title}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set your directive `replace:true` which is *deprecated* by the way. Since you are replacing element your template should compile to a single root.

If you remove `replace` attribute, you can use the template you have now. [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZkWyCVTeKJH1yy6ftdM5?p=preview).

```
   directive('myDir', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E', 
            // don't use deprecated option replace: true
            template: '<input type="text" ng-model="title"> {{title}}'
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When a directive is declared with template (or templateUrl) and replace mode on, the template must have exactly one root element. That is, the text of the template property or the content referenced by the templateUrl must be contained within a single html element.

For example,

```
<p>blah <em>blah</em> blah</p> instead of simply blah <em>blah</em> blah
```

Otherwise, the replacement operation would result in a single element (the directive) being replaced with multiple elements or nodes, which is unsupported and not commonly needed in practice.

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tplrt